# Store Data Using Ajax

Tags: ajax, insert, laravel-5.3

I want to insert data using Ajax in Laravel 5.3.But when I press submit button screen gets refreshed.

My Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //button id//  
  $('#submit').click(function(){

    //form id// 
    $('#new_form').submit(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      var name = $('#name').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/store_form", //controller function
        data: "name="+ name ,
        success: function(){
         alert("sucess");
        });
      });
   });
});
```

How I can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line of the button $('#submit').click(...

And only left the code as follow

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//form id// 
$('#new_form').submit(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $('#name').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/store_form", //controller function
    data: "name="+ name ,
    success: function(){
     alert("sucess");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: above code did not work.any more suggestion to improve code

Comment: i have added coding in blade template. should i make seperate jquery file and how to call that file from blade template

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
//form id// 
$('#new_form').submit(function(e){
```

with only

````
 $('#new_form').submit(function(e){  if you are talking about same form and submit button is ```<input type=submit``` and if there are two forms
````

you can do  `$('#new_form, #new_form2').submit(function(e){`

and add your js with `{!! Html::script('js/script.js') !!}` using `illuminate`
if you are still facing problem please post the error as well as php code.